# Missing number in a list

Tags: python, list, function, sorting, for-loop

I need a little help, a have a list of integers - the difference between the consecutive elements is constant, but the list is unsorted and one element is missing. The function takes a list as an input, the output is an integer (the missing one).

I wrote this code:

```
def missing_number(lst):
    lst.sort()
    diff = lst[1] - lst[0]
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i+1] - lst[i] != diff:
            return int(lst[i] + diff)
```

It's working for this case:  `assert missing_number([1, 4, 2, 5]) == 3`, but I can't make it work for a case like this:  `assert missing_number([2, 6, 8]) == 4` - the difference is more than 1 digit - it's returning 10.

Comment: What is your question? You didn't ask any.

Comment: It must be the case that the missing value is between the largest and smallest value you are given, otherwise the problem is not well formed:  [2, 3, 4] could be missing 1 or 5.  That should give you another way to find the diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear time solution: Compute the sum you'd expect if the number weren't missing, and subtract the actual sum:

```
def missing_number(lst):
    expect = (min(lst) + max(lst)) * (len(lst) + 1) // 2
    return expect - sum(lst)
```

The expected full sum is the average (which is (min+max)/2) multiplied by the number of numbers (which is len+1). I postpone the division until the end since min+max might be odd.

Yours fails the example `[2, 6, 8]` because you compute `diff = 4`, but it should be `2`. You can't just always use `lst[1] - lst[0]`. You could for example use `(lst[-1] - lst[0]) // len(lst)` instead.

Comment: This also failing for case: `missing_number([1,2]) `. Expected output should be 3

Comment: @HarshaBiyani No, as I explained under your answer now (and as Martin explained under the question), the missing number can't be an extreme. So [1,2] is invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't like your code is not working as expected for difference is more than 1 digit.
It is purely because of sequence.
If you try the differ sequence with more with your code, it gonna definitely work. Eg:`assert missing_number([2, 4, 8]) == 6`

So you can not take difference between 1st 2 numbers. You have to take the minimum difference, so you can check by comparing difference with next 2 numbers & take the smallest.

You can try:

```
def missing_number(lst):
    lst.sort()
    final_diff = 0
    diff0 = lst[1] - lst[0]
    diff1 = lst[2] - lst[1]
    if diff0 < diff1:
        final_diff = diff0
    else:
        final_diff = diff1

    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i+1] - lst[i] != final_diff:
            return int(lst[i] + final_diff)

print(missing_number([2, 6, 8]))
```

output:

```
4
```

Comment: Please try to explain your code also point out why the OP's code doesn't work that'd be really helpful.

Comment: @SulemanElahi : I have explained. Please check

Comment: This fails `missing_number([1, 3])`.

Comment: @KellyBundy : If only 2 numbers are there, then there might be 2 different missing numbers. For `[1, 3]` missing number list can be: `[1,2,3]` or `[1,3,5]`

Comment: If a missing extreme were allowed, you'd have the same problem also for more numbers. For example,  [3,4,5,6] could be missing 2 or 7.